# How I can get only active fields false items

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, deep-copy

my scenario

1 - if I do click the button, I am filtering the array by active field as false, and then updating fields as true.

2 - if I do click second time, I want to get objects with only  active fields false.

Result : All items are getting.

[JsFiddle link is here](https://jsfiddle.net/7vdLr3ox/1/)

```js
const test  =[
   {firstName:'abc',lastName:'abc',active:false},
   {firstName:'def',lastName:'def',active:false},
   {firstName:'ghi',lastName:'ghi',active:false},
]

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',()=>{
   const test2 = test.filter(x=>x.active ===false);
        
    console.log(test);
    test2.forEach(x=>{
        x.active=true;
    })
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">
 Get
</button>
```

Comment: If you set them all to `true` the first time, why would there be any that are `false` the second time?

Comment: Your button click event does the same thing with every click. What is misleading you
is that you first console log and then set the active to true

Comment: @pszaba ahhh I think the code should be as I edited but still not what I want.  I think console should be write empty array second click time

Comment: Now I see :) It should have been `console.log(test2)`